# Tooltip is showing when hover on black space

Tags: html, css, tooltip

http://fiddle.jshell.net/9m6a5y5p/

As you can is in demo above, when hover above span element tooltip is shown and i want only to show when hover on span... Yes I know i can use display: none, but i am trying to avoid that...

```
    tooltip {
  color: #E4095C;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip::before,
.tooltip::after {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -100;
  position: absolute;
}

.tooltip:hover::before,
.tooltip:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 100;
}

.tooltip::before {
  content: '';
  border: .825em solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #0D8EAD;
  bottom: 45%;
  left: 35%;
}

.tooltip::after {
  content: attr(data-tip);
  width: 12em;
  padding: .85em;
  background: #0D8EAD;
  bottom: 175%;
  left: 5%;
  margin-left: -3.25em;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add following css after `.tooltip::after{}`

```
.tooltip::after {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Have fun..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pointer-events` to prevent hover events from firing. Add this to your CSS:

```
.tooltip::after {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```